# Why am I getting the error: "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" after iteration 28?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to extract data from an API from my government. The API is divided in pages, and has 10 observations per page. I wrote an algorithm that grabs the important information from each observation and adds it to a pandas dataframe. Everything was going great, until I reach iteration 29, at which I get the error mentioned in the title.

Here's the code I wrote:

```
#Database Creation Using API
#Import Libraries
import requests
import pandas as pd

#Define a list of relevant variables to automatize information acquisition
relevant_vars = ["year","ocid","date","region","title","description","suppliers","buyer","amount"\
                 ,"budget"]#Define a list of relevant variables to automatize information acquisition

#Creation of empty Pandas Dataframe to save all the pertinent information from the database.
data_collected = pd.DataFrame(columns = relevant_vars)

#Access to API's data
#API number 1: "Búsqueda de procesos de contratación por medio de palabra"

#Need an initial response to start while loop
def firstResponse():
    url_t = "https://datosabiertos.compraspublicas.gob.ec/PLATAFORMA/api/search_ocds"
    payload = {"year":"2015","page":"2"}
    r = requests.get(url_t,params = payload).json()
    return r

#Individual information saver.
def infoSave(variables,item):
    rp = firstResponse()
    temp = []
    for i in variables:
        i = rp["data"][item][str(i)]
        temp.append(i)   
    return temp 

#Information gatherer
def infoGet(yr,url,obs=0):
    rp = dict.copy(firstResponse())
    observations = 0
    page_count = 0
    debug_count = 0
    #If no observations parameter is set, automatically gather all available data for that year.
    #Make all the API calls for the specific year (each page represents a call)
    while rp["pages"] - rp["page"] > 1:
        page_count = page_count + 1
        print(page_count)
        url_n = url 
        payload = {"page":str(page_count),"year":str(yr)}
        rp = requests.get(url_n,params=payload).json()
        #Now that the call has been made, save this information in many variables.
        for item in range(len(rp["data"])):
            debug_count = debug_count + 1
            print(f"Iteration no.{debug_count}"+str(infoSave(relevant_vars,item)))
            year, ocid, date, region, title, description, suppliers, buyer, amount, budget = infoSave(relevant_vars,item)
            #After storing the information in the variables, append it to the pandas dataframe
            final_dataframe = data_collected.append({"year":year,"ocid":ocid,"date":date,\
                                                    "region":region,"title":title,\
                                                    "description":description,\
                                                    "suppliers":suppliers,"buyer":buyer,\
                                                    "amount":amount,"budget":budget},ignore_index \
                                                    = True)
        observations = observations + 1
        if obs == 0:
            pass
        elif observations == obs:
            break
```

Then I tried to run the infoGet method:

```
infoGet(2015,"https://datosabiertos.compraspublicas.gob.ec/PLATAFORMA/api/search_ocds",obs=10)
```

Which runs perfectly until iteration 29, when I receive this error message:

---

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18876/3797698545.py in <module>
      1 #Extract the required information from API
----> 2 infoGet(2015,"https://datosabiertos.compraspublicas.gob.ec/PLATAFORMA/api/search_ocds",obs=10)

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18876/506738801.py in infoGet(yr, url, obs)
     47         for item in range(len(rp["data"])):
     48             debug_count = debug_count + 1
---> 49             print(f"Iteration no.{debug_count}"+str(infoSave(relevant_vars,item)))
     50             year, ocid, date, region, title, description, suppliers, buyer, amount, budget = infoSave(relevant_vars,item)
     51             #After storing the information in the variables, append it to the pandas dataframe

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18876/506738801.py in infoSave(variables, item)
     23 #Individual information saver.
     24 def infoSave(variables,item):
---> 25     rp = firstResponse()
     26     temp = []
     27     for i in variables:

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18876/506738801.py in firstResponse()
     18     url_t = "https://datosabiertos.compraspublicas.gob.ec/PLATAFORMA/api/search_ocds"
     19     payload = {"year":"2015","page":"2"}
---> 20     r = requests.get(url_t,params = payload).json()
     21     return r
     22 

D:\ProgramData\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
    908                     # used.
    909                     pass
--> 910         return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
    911 
    912     @property

D:\ProgramData\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    344             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    345             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 346         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    347     if cls is None:
    348         cls = JSONDecoder

D:\ProgramData\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):

D:\ProgramData\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I would be really grateful if somebody could shed some light on why I'm getting this error code specifically when I arrive at this observation. I tried only getting that observation and it works just fine: It has the exact same amount of data as the other observations, and is exactly the same kind of object.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just search for the error message, plenty of similar questions already.

Comment: **Always** check HTTP status code after GET/POST etc

Answer (score 4):

The answer why you get this error is

> The response from the server is not a valid JSON and you are parsing it to a JSON

There can be many reasons, why you don't get the response in JSON. In this case, its a rate limiting in the server. You cannot loop the calls without a delay, as the server allows only certain request burst limits from the same IP.

To fix this issues, you can add a `sleep` condition after every call, increase the pagination size, if the API allows it. You need to find out what is the rate limiting and other restrictions in place for this API.

Also, you should always have a check on the response HTTP status. An ideal response will always have a `HTTP 20X` status and that will be a JSON as agreed in  API specs. At the same time, you might get codes like `HTTP 429 Too Many Requests` or `HTTP 403` or there can be different codes where the response might not be a JSON.

Avoid blind acceptance of content as JSON. Use the response object to check and update your code. An example will be like

```
    response = requests.get(url_n, params=payload)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        rp = response.json()
    else:
        print("Error from server: " + str(response.content))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Kris! To fix my problem I included a try: except: statement. This way, whenever I get an HTTP 429 the function waits 5 seconds (time.sleep(5)) for the API to let me gather the information again.