# How fix this error on python (selenium) - json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Iniciado!
[WDM] - Downloading: 19.0kB [00:00, 19.5MB/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 58, in 
FIREFOX(login)
File "main.py", line 26, in FIREFOX
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
File "C:\Users\moonl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\firefox.py", line 37, in install
driver_path = self.*get_driver_path(self.driver)
File "C:\Users\moonl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\manager.py", line 26, in *get_driver_path
binary_path = self.driver_cache.find_driver(driver)
File "C:\Users\moonl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\driver_cache.py", line 101, in find_driver
metadata = self.get_metadata()
File "C:\Users\moonl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\driver_cache.py", line 135, in get_metadata
return json.load(outfile)
File "C:\Users\moonl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json_*init**.py", line 293, in load
return loads(fp.read(),
File "C:\Users\moonl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json_*init**.py", line 357, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Users\moonl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Users\moonl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8hfl.png)

i am trying to start a selenium program but i get this error

Comment: Please see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Its very unclear, but seems that is libary error. We need see a part of your code that points to json.

See that if you have the:

import json

If you trying to read a txt file as json, try:
with open('/xxxx/xxxxx/xxxx.xxx') as jsonfile:
data = json.load(jsonfile)

Other topic in stackoverflow can help you, please check the awnser in:

[Why am I getting the error: "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" after iteration 28?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71920081/why-am-i-getting-the-error-jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1)

PS: One sugestion, try put Try and Catch in your code and put in some blocks, this help see where the error is on the code. One example is:

```
try
   if xxx.......
   ............
Finnaly
   print some error
```